# Twitter cards not showing when I tweet

Tags: twitter-card

I have set up the following HTML and it passes the Twitter validation tool and shows up fine on there.  When I then send a tweet, no card appears.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="https://trexcant.co.uk" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Small Island Developing States Photo Submission" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Fun t-shirts" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://trexcant.co.uk/images/3.3 tst image.png" />
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about using Twitter and not about running your own website.

Comment: @Stephen I’m not sure this deserves closure, it’s regarding implementing markup on their own website for Twitter card support, similar to how markup is required for rich snippets on Google?

Comment: Please edit it to clarify that and I will be happy to re-open it.   They don't say where those meta tags are going.  It is possible they are trying to get tweets to show up on their website, but if so I don't think they are doing it right.  It would take more than meta tags.